# Slow insert - 300+ Million Records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, insert

The following query takes over an hour on the table to insert.

There are no indexes. There was one which was deleted but still takes an hour after deletion.

Any pointers on improving this appreciated.

```
INSERT  INTO SAPECC_Full.dbo.[vbep]
    ( [MANDT] ,
      [VBELN] ,
      [VBELN_oco] ,
      [POSNR] ,
      [POSNR_oco] ,
      [ETENR] ,
      [ETTYP] ,
      [LFREL] ,
      [EDATU] ,
      [EZEIT] ,
      [WMENG] ,
      [WMENG_oco] ,
      [BMENG] ,
      [BMENG_oco] ,
      [VRKME] ,
      [LMENG] ,
      [MEINS] ,
      [BDDAT] ,
      [BDART] ,
      [PLART] ,
      [VBELE] ,
      [POSNE] ,
      [ETENE] ,
      [RSDAT] ,
      [IDNNR] ,
      [BANFN] ,
      [BANFN_oco] ,
      [BSART] ,
      [BSTYP] ,
      [WEPOS] ,
      [REPOS] ,
      [LRGDT] ,
      [PRGRS] ,
      [TDDAT] ,
      [MBDAT] ,
      [LDDAT] ,
      [LDDAT_oco] ,
      [WADAT] ,
      [CMENG] ,
      [LIFSP] ,
      [GRSTR] ,
      [ABART] ,
      [ABRUF] ,
      [ROMS1] ,
      [ROMS2] ,
      [ROMS3] ,
      [ROMEI] ,
      [RFORM] ,
      [UMVKZ] ,
      [UMVKN] ,
      [VERFP] ,
      [BWART] ,
      [BNFPO] ,
      [ETART] ,
      [AUFNR] ,
      [PLNUM] ,
      [SERNR] ,
      [AESKD] ,
      [ABGES] ,
      [MBUHR] ,
      [TDUHR] ,
      [LDUHR] ,
      [WAUHR] ,
      [AULWE] ,
      OcoDateChanged
    )
    SELECT  RTRIM([MANDT]) ,
            RTRIM([VBELN]) ,
            dbo.SAPLeading0s(VBELN) ,
            RTRIM([POSNR]) ,
            dbo.SAPLeading0s(POSNR) ,
            RTRIM([ETENR]) ,
            RTRIM([ETTYP]) ,
            RTRIM([LFREL]) ,
            RTRIM([EDATU]) ,
            RTRIM([EZEIT]) ,
            RTRIM([WMENG]) ,
            dbo.SAPNumeric(WMENG) ,
            RTRIM([BMENG]) ,
            dbo.SAPNumeric(BMENG) ,
            RTRIM([VRKME]) ,
            RTRIM([LMENG]) ,
            RTRIM([MEINS]) ,
            RTRIM([BDDAT]) ,
            RTRIM([BDART]) ,
            RTRIM([PLART]) ,
            RTRIM([VBELE]) ,
            RTRIM([POSNE]) ,
            RTRIM([ETENE]) ,
            RTRIM([RSDAT]) ,
            RTRIM([IDNNR]) ,
            RTRIM([BANFN]) ,
            dbo.SAPLeading0s(BANFN) ,
            RTRIM([BSART]) ,
            RTRIM([BSTYP]) ,
            RTRIM([WEPOS]) ,
            RTRIM([REPOS]) ,
            RTRIM([LRGDT]) ,
            RTRIM([PRGRS]) ,
            RTRIM([TDDAT]) ,
            RTRIM([MBDAT]) ,
            RTRIM([LDDAT]) ,
            dbo.SAPDate(LDDAT) ,
            RTRIM([WADAT]) ,
            RTRIM([CMENG]) ,
            RTRIM([LIFSP]) ,
            RTRIM([GRSTR]) ,
            RTRIM([ABART]) ,
            RTRIM([ABRUF]) ,
            RTRIM([ROMS1]) ,
            RTRIM([ROMS2]) ,
            RTRIM([ROMS3]) ,
            RTRIM([ROMEI]) ,
            RTRIM([RFORM]) ,
            RTRIM([UMVKZ]) ,
            RTRIM([UMVKN]) ,
            RTRIM([VERFP]) ,
            RTRIM([BWART]) ,
            RTRIM([BNFPO]) ,
            RTRIM([ETART]) ,
            RTRIM([AUFNR]) ,
            RTRIM([PLNUM]) ,
            RTRIM([SERNR]) ,
            RTRIM([AESKD]) ,
            RTRIM([ABGES]) ,
            RTRIM([MBUHR]) ,
            RTRIM([TDUHR]) ,
            RTRIM([LDUHR]) ,
            RTRIM([WAUHR]) ,
            RTRIM([AULWE]) ,
            GETDATE()
    FROM    vbep_full
```

Comment: The function SAPLeading0s just removes 0s at the beginning. Similar to cast as int/bigint but not be converted. Column needs to remain as text.

Comment: How long time does it take if you remove the calls to UDF's?

Comment: Completes about 150M rows in ~10mins, but takes another 20mins for the other 150M.

Comment: Do you have enough (without having to do auto-growth) pre-allocated space in the DB to hold the new table?

Comment: auto-growth is set to 20%, and several tables in the db are truncated and loaded each day.. so i assuming there is space. Otherwise, any pointers to double-check or change the same? (unless you are referring to mdf ldf sizes.. which i know where to check)

Comment: That was @MikaelEriksson's point, if you have enough space pre-allocated for the mdf/ldf files and don't have to endure auto-growth operations (which are IO expensive and occur at worse time possible - during your load).

Comment: Why are you assuming there is enough space when you could check (e.g. monitor for growth events)? Did you check the log file settings and what it's doing during this time? Did you check dm exec requests, dm os waiting tasks etc. to see what the insert is spending time on?

Comment: Will check and post dm exec requests/os waiting tasks tomorrow. Have temporarily bumped up the pre-allocated space from 430G to 500G for the mdf.

Comment: You have a performance problem and so analyze it like a performance problem: **measure**. Collect wait stats, performance counters, identity the bottleneck. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking SQL Server to perform 19.5 Billion string manipulations (300,000,000 rows X 65 columns), all in one giant transaction.  That is assuming vbep_Full is a regular table with simple column definitions (not a view with joins to other tables and/or with computed comlumns).

If your CPU is not maxed out, you could try breaking the work into multiple parts, process each part in parallel.

I would also recommend working in small batches with implicit transactions.  That way if one of the batches fails, you could start that batch over again without having to start the other batches over.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a whole lot of aggregation.

I'd start tweeking the MAXDOP option for the query.

If you can see the wait types, and you notice a CXPACKET alot for this query, I would set it for 1, else start messing with it to have it scale out the query.